# Can I use Java to do game programming for Xbox-one and self publish it?

Tags: java, xbox

I am wondering whether i can use java to write games for xbox-one? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft has its own framework for games on Xbox (360 or One) and I'm pretty sure it works only with C# and not with Java (by the way I don't think java is a pretty good solution to create games)

Comment: actually java is becoming increasingly used for game developement

Answer (score 1):

It was not possible for the Xbox 360, so i guess it will be the same for the Xbox One.

On [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live_Indie_Games#Game_development) Wikipedia article about developing Indie Games, they say:

> **Create** – Games are written in **C#** or **Visual Basic .NET** using the **XNA Game Studio framework**, allowing the developers to debug and test their game internally before release. The final code is compiled into a single binary package.

So the answer is that you can't develop games in Java for Xbox One.

Comment: But MS no longer supports XNA, so why would you use XNA to develop Xbox One?

Answer (score 0):

You from my knowledge, cannot. But, if you know java, C# is pretty similar, so learning it will be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can use something like IKVM.NET to run Java in the .NET VM.
Or you can compile Java to machine code.